# Select objects without some properties in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have one problem in Symfony that I cannot solve.
I have one Entity class e.g. Category where I have e.g. $id, $name, $description, OneToMany User[] $members, OneToMany Book[] $books
Now... I need to get all categories (e.g. WHERE description IS NOT NULL) but in results, I don't want to have $books.
I need Category with id, name, description and [member1, member2...] but **NO** books.
I use something like:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();
```

Comment: You can select which field you want in your query https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples you should look into doctrine documentation to understand better how to query things

Comment: I am trying to write custom query but there is no success for me :(

Comment: @JaroslavBeredi How do you mean by "but **NO** books"? Doctrine by default uses Lazy fetching, meaning the books are not queried until after you call `$category->getBooks()`, unless the `fetch` declaration was changed in your mapping. For your custom query, please update your question with what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->select('fieldA, fieldB')` to [query specific fields](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples).

Create a method in your repository to make your custom query:

```
public function findAllWithoutBooks()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id, c.name, c.description')
        ->leftJoin('c.members', 'm')
        ->addSelect('m.id AS member_id, m.name AS member_name')
        ->andWhere('c.description IS NOT NULL')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
}
```

And use it like any other method:

```
$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAllWithoutBooks();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I try only id and members for simple understanding.
When I dump(query) I have this query: SELECT c.id, c.members FROM AppBundle\Entity\Category c WHERE c.description IS NOT NULL
But result of running getResult is: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'members FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
Do I have to join Users somehow?

Comment: It's important to note that calling the specific column names will cause the hydrator to provide an array of scalar values as opposed to an array of Category objects. EG: `$category[0]['name']` instead of `$category->getName()`. Additionally `c.members` would need to be changed to a `JOIN`. `->leftJoin('c.members', 'm')->addSelect('m.id AS member_id, m.name AS member_name')` See *LEFT JOIN to hydrate all user-ids and optionally associated article-ids*

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine by default uses Lazy fetching, meaning the books are not queried until after you call `$category->getBooks()`. Using partial references is not needed as detailed below, unless the mapping `fetch` declaration was changed to `EAGER` for the association, provided you are not calling `$category->getBooks();`

Alternatively, a custom query using the [`partial`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/partial-objects.html) keyword can be used to explicitly select only the specified fields and hydrate partial `Category` and associated `User` objects.

> Use of partial objects is tricky. Fields that are not retrieved from the database will not be updated by the `UnitOfWork` even if they get changed in your objects. You can only promote a partial object to a fully-loaded object by calling `EntityManager#refresh()` or a DQL query with the refresh flag.

**Example Query**

```
$qb = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->createQueryBuilder('c');
$categories = $qb->select('partial c.{id, name, description}')
   ->leftJoin('c.members', 'm')
   ->addSelect('partial m.{id, name}')
   ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('c.description'))
   ->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

**Result**

```
array(
    Category {
        id,
        name,
        description,
        members => array(
            User {
                id,
                name
            },
            User {
                id,
                name
            }
            ...
        ),
    },
    Category {
        id,
        name,
        description,
        members => array(
            User {
                id,
                name
            },
            User {
                id,
                name
            }
            ...
        )
    }
    ...
)
```